# Menu module in joomla not showing all menu items added

Tags: html, css, joomla, menu

Please I need help with this. I am using joomla version 3.6.5 and installed greenlife template. I want to add menu module to the site. I added two menu modules. One is menu prinicipal and the other is les attractions. I also created two menus which are main menu and main menu2. i added main menu to menu principal menu module and main menu2 to les atrractions menu module. It display on the site correctly. But my problem now is only two menu items is showing on each menu module. I have more than two menu items in each menu which are main menu and main menu2 Please help me.

[image: menu module display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use default Joomla template (protostar). Do you solve the issue?
If you unpublish first two menu items, do you see other menu items or menu disappear completely?

Comment: Yes, it shows the next two menu items when I unpublish the first two menu items

Comment: When I use default theme, it's working correctly. But I want it to work on the theme I want too

Comment: Yes, I know, it was a test.

Comment: I don't know that template but know we understand that the issue is related to the template. Maybe the css or an override. You have to inspect these.

Comment: I'm going to check out the template. Could you please give me an url?

Comment: Thanks.. You can download the template here https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhao6v48vfkeybc/greenlife.rar?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139701/discussion-between-jegger-and-amjos-com).